# mount a local directory to a remote ssh server

Tags: ssh, mount, sshfs

i want to mount a local directory to a remote ssh server. specifically my ~/.gnupg directory so i can use my local keyring everywhere, without storing it remotely.

so i think this solution:

- keep a local ssh server opened (firewalled as you like)
- ssh to remote forwarding local:22 to remote:10000
- launch sshfs to mount localhost:10000:.gnupg to ~/.gnupg

i put this in my ssh/config:

```
Host remote
        HostName remotehost
        RemoteForward 10000 localhost:22
        User user
        PermitLocalCommand yes
        LocalCommand sshfs -p 10000 user@127.0.0.1:/Users/remoteuser/.gnupg .gnupg
```

doing ssh, i get:

```
fuse: bad mount point `.gnupg': No such file or directory
```

if i ran the sshfs manually after the ssh login everything works fine. so i guess that the LocalCommand directive is execute before RemoteForward.
how to solve this?

Comment: Try using a full path for the last .gnupg ... ssh does not necessarily have the same working directory as your shell.

Comment: @barrycarter: same result  

    fuse: bad mount point `/home/rob/.gnupg': No such file or directory

Comment: So, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem: `ssh`'s `LocalCommand` is executed on the **local** (client) side, not the remote as you wish.  There is no `RemoteCommand` option, but you can hack the functionality into your config file.   Note, all of these assume that your `remotehost:.gnupg` directory exists before hand.

**Option 1:** Use two separate host specifications in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote
    HostName remotehost
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand ssh -f %r@%n-mount -p %p sshfs -p 10000 %u@localhost:%d/.gnupg .gnupg

Host remote-mount
    HostName remotehost
    ForwardAgent yes
    RemoteForward 10000 localhost:22
```

Downsides: both entries need to exit for **each** host you want this mount point.

**Option 2:** Combine ssh options and port forwarding into LocalCommand:

```
Host remote
    HostName remotehost
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand ssh -f %r@%h -o RemoteForward="10000 localhost:22" -o ForwardAgent=yes -p %p sshfs -p 10000 %u@localhost:%d/.gnupg .gnupg
```

Note the subtle difference in the two `LocalCommand` lines is the use of %n in the first example and %h in the second.  This will work, but has one huge **ASSUMPTION**: you **NEVER** ssh to a host by it's true name and only via "short names" that exist in your `.ssh/config` file, otherwise you'll end up with a infinite loop of `ssh` connections trying to execute your `LocalCommand`.

**Option 3:** Use SSH Multiplexing to setup only one connection to the remote:

```
Host remote
    HostName remotehost
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand ssh -f %r@%h -o RemoteForward="10000 localhost:22" -o ForwardAgent=yes -p %p sshfs -p 10000 %u@localhost:%d/.gnupg .gnupg
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 30m
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
```

I think that's the only winning solution, and can even work in `Host *` rules, AND doesn't suffer from any downsides.  It even solves the issue that second ssh sessions to the same host will NOT attempt to remount the same directory via sshfs.

**Caveat:**  One final issue I've not bothered to resolve:  your remote `sshfs` will persist long after you log out of the remote host.  In fact, it will never `unmount`, unless your localhost goes offline or the connection is otherwise broken.

You could look at some other option to `umount` that `sshfs` mount as you log out of the remote host, perhaps using [ideas such as this](https://serverfault.com/questions/448961/execute-commands-on-user-login-logout).  Or you could play games with the `LocalCommand` to execute something that watches and self-umounts after it sees some trigger event occur, but seems fragile at best.

Another option would be to wrap `ssh` commands in some shell or perhaps use `ProxyCommand` to do something tricky, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Note: Since OpenSSH 7.6 there is now a RemoteCommand option: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6